# how to make Kafka consumer detect non-existent topics and remove them from metadata?

Tags: apache-kafka

My KafkaConsumer subscribes a pattern of topics. However when deleting some outdated topics, It hits UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION exception when fetching metadata from cluster because the consumer client still maintains the deleted topic in its topic list. Those outdated topics info will never expire in the consumer so I must restart consumer to remove them. Any ideas to let consumer remove topics in this metadata when they dont exist in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka clients refresh their metadata regularly (by default every 5 mins). Next time the client will get refresh it metadata, it will remove topics that have been deleted from its cache.

You can configure how often metadata are refreshed using `metadata.max.age.ms`, see the [Consumer configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs).

Comment: It seems that only working on producer. I looked up the source code and found only producer regular removed unused topic while consumer just discovers new topic